# Can't get data frame to stop turning values into variables?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new and trying to create a dataset that contains information about the values within its related datasets which already exist.  It involves counting the # of times two variables show up in their datasets separately.  I didn't want to crowd my final command with long strings so I made separate variables for the counts:

```
df1a <- count(filter(df1,a_b == "a"))
```

and the intended frame:

```r
X <- data.frame(A=rep(c('1','2'...'12'), each=2),
                B=rep(c('a','b'), times=12),
                C=c((df1a),(df1b),(df2a)...(df12b)))
```

So it can actually read the sets created as the count values but is just creating more columns that have headers of C.n1, C.n2... and the actual value they represent repeats throughout the whole column.  I really need them all to be one column and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In your case, `count()` returns a `data.frame` object. You need `df1a <- as.integer(count(filter(df1,a_b == "a")))`.

Comment: @LTyrone Yes, thank you that helped immensely.  I mean it also added an L to the end of the count # but that's probably just something weird with the datasets themselves.

Comment: The "L" is a bit confusing at first but it is an R label letting you know the number is an integer, it's not part of the object and won't show in column  C of your X dataframe when you run `view(X)`. To illustrate, run `as.character(1L)` and then `1L + 1L` and examine the results.